# Motivate a proof that $a \sin ct + b \cos ct$ is the unique solution to the ODE for simple harmonic motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at an Exercise in the first chapter of the first volume of Princeton Lectures in Analysis.

---

[image: Exercise 1.6]

---

When you follow the hint you get $g'(t) = h'(t) = 0$, so assigning $g(t) = a$ and $h(t) = b$ and doing a bit of algebra you can obtain the desired result: $f(t) = a \cos ct + b \sin ct$.  But if I didn't have the hint, how would I manage to find $g(t)$ and $h(t)$?  I mean I guess I could sit around and wait for inspiration, but I'm not that smart.

Comment: These things aren't really intuitive when you first learn them (they weren't for me anyway), it just takes time. The approach in the lecture notes is a pretty standard technique to show uniqueness of solutions for some simple ODEs. It is much the same as showing $f' = f$ has solution $f = Ae^{t}$ by considering the function $g = fe^{-t}$ and, using the original ODE, showing $g' = 0 \implies g = \text{constant} \implies f = \text{constant } e^{t}$.